# Top Tag Hits Aggregation across Multiple Type in Single Object

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to search data across multiple types in Elastic Search. Both the types are present inside a single Index. I am doing a tog tags hits to fetch some fields from both the types. But it seems the data from each type is being returned as a separate object.

How can we have data from different types in a single object under hits.

Update

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "and": [

          {
            "or": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "Type1.fieldName": "55259"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "Type2.fieldName": "55259"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "top_tag_hits": {
      "top_hits": {
        "_source": {
          "include": [
            "Type1.field1",
            "Type2.field2"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am searching in Type 1 & Type 2 and I have specified the fields in top tag hits. But the hits array is returning a separate source object for Type 1 & Type 2.
I am looking for a way to have a single source object in hits having fields from both Type 1 & Type 2

Comment: I invite you to provide some sample documents, queries and results to better picture what you're experiencing and what you expect instead. It will be easier for people to help you out.

Comment: Please use these guidelines to provide more info: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Updated Post with Request.